# Castor Marshaling :: Invalid XML Character

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, castor

I am using **castor** API for converting an object to XML.

I get the following exception

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: The character '' is an invalid XML character.

I know the correct approach is to correct the source but there are a lot of such invalid characters.

In another forum, someone suggested to encode the java object contents before marshaling them and then decode the output (`Base64`). The approach appears pretty cumbersome and does not fit the solution properly.

I need a way to skip these characters during marshaling and the XML generated should contain the characters as it is.

Comment: After digging a bit more, I found that the invalid character is nothing but a backspace(ASCII Code = 8). Its strange how a backspace character got inserted into a string. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: encode the java object contents before marshalling them and decode after unmarshalling. This seems to be the only way of resolving this. marshal.setEncoding("base64");  used base 64 encoding and decoding.

Comment: I don't think using base64 to be appropriate since this isn't binary data. The below answer does help though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 /**
     * This method ensures that the output String has only
     * valid XML unicode characters as specified by the
     * XML 1.0 standard. For reference, please see
     * <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Char">the
     * standard</a>. This method will return an empty
     * String if the input is null or empty.
     *
     * @param in The String whose non-valid characters we want to remove.
     * @return The in String, stripped of non-valid characters.
     */
    public String stripNonValidXMLCharacters(String in) {
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(); // Used to hold the output.
        char current; // Used to reference the current character.

        if (in == null || ("".equals(in))) return ""; // vacancy test.
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
            current = in.charAt(i); // NOTE: No IndexOutOfBoundsException caught here; it should not happen.
            if ((current == 0x9) ||
                (current == 0xA) ||
                (current == 0xD) ||
                ((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF)) ||
                ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD)) ||
                ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF)))
                out.append(current);
        }
        return out.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want generated XML to contain this kind of

> characters as it is

, then XML 1.1 specification might help.
Castor can be configured to marshal into XML 1.1 with custom `org.exolab.castor.xml.XMLSerializerFactory` and  `org.exolab.castor.xml.Serializer` implementations:

```
package com.foo.castor;
......

import org.exolab.castor.xml.BaseXercesOutputFormat;
import org.exolab.castor.xml.Serializer;
import org.exolab.castor.xml.XMLSerializerFactory;
import org.xml.sax.DocumentHandler;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XML11Serializer;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CastorXml11SerializerFactory implements XMLSerializerFactory {

    private static class CastorXml11OutputFormat extends BaseXercesOutputFormat{

        public CastorXml11OutputFormat(){
            super._outputFormat = new OutputFormat();
        }
    }

    private static class CastorXml11Serializer implements Serializer {

        private XML11Serializer serializer = new XML11Serializer();

        @Override
        public void setOutputCharStream(Writer out) {
            serializer.setOutputCharStream(out);
        }

        @Override
        public DocumentHandler asDocumentHandler() throws IOException {
            return serializer.asDocumentHandler();
        }

        @Override
        public void setOutputFormat(org.exolab.castor.xml.OutputFormat format) {
            serializer.setOutputFormat((OutputFormat)format.getFormat());
        }

        @Override
        public void setOutputByteStream(OutputStream output) {
            serializer.setOutputByteStream(output);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Serializer getSerializer() {
        return new CastorXml11Serializer();
    }

    @Override
    public org.exolab.castor.xml.OutputFormat getOutputFormat() {
        return new CastorXml11OutputFormat();
    }

}
```

in `castor.properties` file globally

```
org.exolab.castor.xml.serializer.factory=com.foo.castor.CastorXml11SerializerFactory
org.exolab.castor.xml.version=1.1
```

or set these two properties by `setCastorProperties` method of your particular `CastorMarshaller`.

Please be advised, however, that [XML 1.1 is not accepted by browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508283/xml-version-1-1-not-accepted-by-browsers) and [not all XML parsers can parse XML 1.1 out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312517/how-can-i-parse-xml-that-confirms-to-the-1-1-spec-using-java-and-xerces).